# Python recursion return differs

Tags: python, recursion

The return of a python recusion differs and I do not understand why:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def recurse_table(table, table_list):
    if table.find_next("table") is not None:
        recurse_table(table.find_next("table"), table_list)
    table_list.append(table)
    return table_list


fp = open("tc4400_cs_2.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), features="html.parser")
print(len(recurse_table(soup.find("table"), [])))
```

returns correct length (4).

Whereas

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def recurse_table(table, table_list):
    if table.find_next("table") is not None:
        recurse_table(table.find_next("table"), table_list)
    return table_list.append(table)


fp = open("tc4400_cs_2.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), features="html.parser")
print(len(recurse_table(soup.find("table"), [])))
```

returns TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The return differs because what you're returning differs. The `.append()` method modifies `table_list` but does not return it, instead it returns a `None`. If you want to return the list, then you should append `table` to the list in one line and then in the next return the list, just like you already do in the first code.